# MSIL opcode: br vs br.s?

Tags: c#, .net, assembly, cil

What are differences between MSIL opcodes: **br** and **br.s**?

> 0x38  br  Branch to target.

vs

> 0x2B  br.s  Branch to target, short form.

Comment: Sounds like a short jump, near jump and far jump from assembler - but why would one need this in IL? The JIT compiler should find that out himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.br_s(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The target instruction is represented as a 1-byte signed offset from the beginning of the instruction following the current instruction.

The difference is the size of the target, most jumps happen close around a location so it makes sense to optimize this instruction for size, reducing the total size of the IL, which may have several benefits (faster load times, smaller `.dll` sizes, etc)